# Static path Express + Nginx

Tags: node.js, express, nginx

I have very strange behavior in my application. I want to add multiply static path to my app.js file.

First for main application:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

And second for landing pages which located in 'ads' directory.

```
app.use('/ads', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'ads')));
```

Folder structure:

```
public
 - build
  - ...
ads
 - currency
   - public
     - build
      - 1.css
      - 2.js
   - index.html
...
app.js
```

In my main application all JS and CSS files loading successfully, but when i get in to path /ads/currency my index.html loaded but .css, .js and images don't. However if i pass to command line /ads/currency/public/build/1.css it is loading normal.

Does someone know about it?

Screenshots was attached:
[image] 
[image]

Nginx config:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has nothing to do with your configuration but might be related to Chrome (i.e. an extension), since the error says `ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT`.

Check your ad blockers log. The keyword *ads* in the path might be blocked, since a filter might try to catch a javascript miner.

You should make sure the move the whole "ads" part into a different folder - avoiding the keyword "ads" at all. Disabling the ad blocker might work for you know, bot not for your users

Comment: Thank you so much))) It is really 'AdBlock' blocking /ads - url ) Shame to me )-:

Comment: Right, it was obviously the *ads* and not the *crypto* part... (;

Comment: Make sure the move the whole "ads" part into a different folder. Disabling the ad blocker might work for you know, bot not for your users. Adding this to the answer.

Comment: Yes)) I changed 'ads' to 'lp' and this began to work)